# How do I resize a canvas when entering fullscreen with canvas.requestFullscreen()?

Tags: animation, canvas, resize, fullscreen, dart

Alright, so I have this grid that I would like to have full-screen and draw on within the complete space of the resolution.

But I can't get it to register for more than maybe 2/3 thirds of the screen.

I have a `CanvasElement` inside a self-made `Grid`-class. When you press a button, the grid should go fullscreen by this method:

```dart
void fullScreenRequest(){      
  document.onFullscreenChange.listen(grid.handleFullScreen());
  grid.requestFullscreen();      
}
```

This triggers these methods inside the `Grid`:

```dart
void requestFullscreen(){       
   canvas.requestFullscreen();       
}

void handleFullScreen(){              
   window.setImmediate(() {         
       canvas.width = (canvas.parent as Element).client.width;
       canvas.height = (canvas.parent as Element).client.height;         

       canvasWidth = canvas.width;
       canvasHeight = canvas.height;        
   });       
 }
```

When drawing the content of the grid I use `canvasWidth` and `canvasHeight` as bases. How do I get these values to become the full resolution of the screen?

Comment: `document.onFullscreenChange.listen(grid.handleFullScreen());`  I guess you already figured out that you are actually calling the `handleFullScreen` listener right away instead of attaching it...

Answer (score 2):

Just take the window size in your callback:

```dart
canvas.width = window.innerWidth; // Or window.screen.available.width
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
canvas.style.position = 'absolute'; // If you need
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
:-webkit-full-screen #CanvasElement {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

as suggested [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode)

Answer (score 0):

I used this:

```
original_width = canvas.width;
original_height = canvas.height;
canvas.onFullscreenChange.listen( (t){
  if( canvas == document.fullscreenElement ){
    canvas.width = window.screen.width;
    canvas.height = window.screen.height;
  }
  else{
    canvas.width = original_width;
    canvas.height = original_height;
  }
} );
```

**document.fullscreenElement** returns the element currently in fullscreen, and is used to restore the size when exiting the fullscreen again.

**window.screen.height** returns the full screen height, while **window.screen.available.height** returns the screen height, excluding the space reserved for taskbars and similar in your desktop environment. Do not use the latter, nor many of the solutions like **document.body.clientHeight**, **canvas.offsetHeight**, etc. you find around the web, they will not give the size you want.